# Improve system response by looking at transfer functions

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, system

This question is quite long - I apologize for that.

I am working on a car in a course project. In order for the car to drive efficiently, it has to have a \$\lambda \$-value of \$\lambda=1.3 \$ for each RPM-interval in its injection LUT. The only way to control the \$\lambda \$-value is to adjust the injection lengths in the LUT:-

[image]

We can make the car perform an auto tuning such that the car itself finds at which injection length in each RPM-interval will result in a \$\lambda \$-value of 1.3. However, this takes a long time. It takes about 8 sweeps before the \$\lambda \$-value is about 1.3 in each RPM interval which is too long. Our input during the tuning is \$\lambda_{ref}=1.3 \$ and our output is \$\lambda_{measured} \$.

**Our thoughts on a solution**

If we can find the transfer function between \$\lambda_{ref}\$ and \$\lambda_{measured} \$ then we can look at the Bode plot and maybe find a solution to the long settling time. We collected data from the car's **closed loop system** and found the relation between \$\lambda_{measured} \$ as a function of sweeps.

[image]

We can then in MATLAB find the transfer function between \$\lambda_{ref} \$ and \$\lambda_{measured} \$ by using the system identification tool and estimating a (continuous) transfer function \$H(s) \$. However, since our data was for the closed loop system, we actually find \$H_{cl}(s) \$ and to find the **open loop** transfer function we do \$H_{ol}(s) = \frac{H{cl}(s)}{1-H_{cl}(s)} \$.

And finally we can look at the Bode plot of the open loop system as solve the problem with the long settling time, maybe by increasing the crossover frequency or whatever.

**My question**

Is our process the right way to go or are we way off track here? Can we even implement the things we find since our transfer functions found with the SISO-tool are just estimates? Is there a better way to think about this, or can it work? I hope I can get some guidance cause I feel like we are in deep waters.

**Explanation**

A sweep: The car engine stars at 0RPM in first gear, speeds up to about 3000RPM, then switches to 2nd gear and speeds up from about 1800RPM to 4000RPM. Then the engine stops and the wheels have to be manually slowed down.

The autotuner starts at a standard injection length and adjusts the injection lengths give out the desired \$\lambda \$-value with this formula
$$ t_{inj} = t_{inj,old}+(\lambda_{desired}-\lambda_{measured})\cdot K_p$$
where \$K_p \$ is a correction value.

The system does have a controller, but I am not sure if it is linear closed loop. I think the current controller is a PI-controller, which I can modify in the ECU code.

I can change the reference, for example setting \$\lambda_{ref}=1 \$.

Comment: What do you mean by a sweep, could you go into more detail on how that works? Does the auto-tuner try a sequence of many injection values on each of those sweeps? Also, how many times a second can you actually change the injection value? You mention that the system already has a (linear) closed loop control, are you sure about it? And can you modify that loop or only change its reference?

Comment: @jDAQ I have added an explanation below. Hopefully it gives some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the adjustments done by the auto-tuner fits the description of a P controller (red terms) with a feed-forward term (blue term).

$$ t_{inj} = \color{blue}{t_{inj,old}}+ \color{red}{ (\lambda_{desired}-\lambda_{measured})\cdot K_p }$$

If you can alter the ECU code to adjust its PI-controller, and if it is safe to alter it, you could try some experimental tuning methods to find a decent PI-controller for it. That being said, if you use system identification tools to model the system you can use simulations and other design tools to find the PI-controller.

Identifying it from the closed-loop data might not give you a result as good as using a frequency sweep or inputting white noise into the system. In part because, the open loop transfer function you will identify will include the controller that is already being used, and you don't seem to know the structure of the current controller.

> Is our process the right way to go or are we way off track here?

Yes. Just make sure to remember that the identified TF includes the current controller, you will identify the controller+plant open loop transfer function. Also, take into account the limitations of your actuator (the valid range for \$t_{inj}\$) when designing your controller.

> Can we even implement the things we find since our transfer functions found with the SISO-tool are just estimates?

No physical system is really linear, or time-invariant. All transfer functions are approximations. So if you do find a good estimate of the TF that fits your system you can definitely use it to design your new controller.

> Is there a better way to think about this, or can it work?

Without knowing more about your system, I can't say if there is a a better way to do all that.